# Why am I getting `ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero` error?

Tags: python, function, division, zero, inverse

I want to find a function's x value at y=0.

```
from pynverse import inversefunc
from math import pi,sqrt
R=20
C=5*10**-9
L=5*10**-4
Z= (lambda x: sqrt(R**2+(1/(2*pi*C*x)-2*pi*L*x)**2))
inversefunc(Z,y_values=0)
```

But I get following error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
inversefunc(Z,y_values=0)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pynverse\inverse.py", line 113, in inversefunc
trend = np.sign(func(ref2, *args) - func(ref1, *args))
File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <lambda>
Z= (lambda x: sqrt(R**2+(1/(2*pi*C*x)-2*pi*L*x)**2))
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Please help me why! Thank you.

Comment: What should happen when `x=0`?

Answer (score 0):

You can inform that the answer is undefined when the divisor is 0, and you should use normal functions, not named lambdas in python.

```
from pynverse import inversefunc
from math import pi,sqrt


def Z(x):
    # Can define these globally if necessary.
    R = 20
    C = 5 * 10**-9
    L = 5 * 10**-4

    return sqrt(R**2 + (1/(2*pi*C*x) - 2*pi*L*x)**2))


try:
    inversefunc(Z, y_values=0)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("answer is undefined")
```